# Deactivate tomcat session

Tags: tomcat, logout

I have a project on my work and i log-in as a tomcat user but i don't know how to log out, i try deactivate tomcat session, we use java spring and here is what i try to do from the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/logout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView logoutAction(HttpSession session, ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) {
    logger.info("Start HomeController.logoutAction");
    session.invalidate();
    request.getSession(true);
    logger.info("End HomeController.logoutAction");
    return new ModelAndView("home");
}
```

but when i redirected in home page i don't prompted for username or password. Does anyone now how i can do this?

Comment: Do you use spring security? What does your context look like?

Comment: As far as i know we just configure tomcat to have some users for our project. There is nothing to do with context.xml, also we for now we don't use security.xml. There were just tomcat users with appropriate privilege.

Comment: Ok i figured what i have to do. This post http://grokbase.com/t/tomcat/users/02a8k075m6/session-invalidate-does-not-work  explains that i have to destroy and recreate a new session of my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer for the above question. I had seen a lot of answers on internet but all were the same. Finally from a guy i realize that you have to send wrong verification data to server (username and password), so that guy have write this:

```
function logout(safeLocation){
    var mainWindow = window;
    invalidateCurentSession();
    var outcome, u, m = "You should be logged out now.";
    // IE has a simple solution for it - API:
    try { outcome = document.execCommand("ClearAuthenticationCache") }catch(e){}
    // Other browsers need a larger solution - AJAX call with special user name - 'logout'.
    if (!outcome) {
        // Let's create an xmlhttp object
        outcome = (function(x){
            if (x) {
                // the reason we use "random" value for password is 
                // that browsers cache requests. changing
                // password effectively behaves like cache-busing.
                x.open("HEAD", safeLocation || location.href, true, "logout", "wrongUser");
                x.send("");
                // x.abort()
                return 1;// this is **speculative** "We are done." 
            } else {
                return;
            }
        })(mainWindow.XMLHttpRequest ? new mainWindow.XMLHttpRequest() : console.log("active"))
    }
    if (!outcome) {
        m = "Your browser is too old or too weird to support log out functionality. Close all windows and restart the browser."
    }
    window.location = "some url";
    return outcome;
}
```

Use the above javascript function, create a link (Log out) which calls this function:

```
<a href='javascript:logout()'>logout</a>
```

Or as the first method in a logout page.

(P.S. sorry but i don't remember the site url)